# Control over global variable in threads

Tags: pthreads, embedded-linux

Q1)I have an application that does functionality as shown below. I needed a mechanism to wait for the response based on the global count variable. Until then each thread invoked is slept.

Ans. We can use a structure to send as arguements to pthread_create()

```
typedef args
{
    int arg;
    int gcount;
}sargs;

sargs threadarg[3];

int main()
{
    /** Pass the structure after initializing to pthread_create() and access
    these values when required*/
}
```

Q2) Can I bind every thread with same function without any race conditions.?

Ans. Yes

Pseudo code:

```
int gcount[3];
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

main()
{
    pthread_t th[3];
    int arg[3];
    gcount[0]=10;
    gcount[1]=10;
    gcount[2]=10;


    // arg array is filled up with 3 different data values 

    // "same_func()" function is used to invoke the threads with different arg' values
    for( i =0; i< 3; i++)
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, same_func, arg[i]);

   for( i = 0;i <3; i++ )
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL)

    return 0;
}

void same_func( void *val)
{
   //Perform sending of this val using send() function for 10 times in each thread.
   // Basically I will be sending some specific data along with "val"

  //This part is troubling me.
  // I need to wait on until the global count decreases based on callback function as shown
  // I am not sure of using "gcount" variable in this way. Wants inputs in here.

   while( gcount[0] > 0 || gcount[1] > 0 || gcount[2] >0 )
       sleep(1);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// This function is invoked when I receive response to the above send()
void callback( void *val)
{
  //Performs some work

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

   if(val == arg[0])
       gcount[0]--;

   if(val == arg[1])
       gcount[1]--;

   if(val == arg[2])
       gcount[2]--;

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    
}
```

Q3) Also, when I call pthread_join().. Will it wait until my thread keeps waiting. Or will it return some error value and makes the thread "a zombie" ??

Ans. Pthread_join() will safely join this "worker" thread invoked to the so called "master"
thread from where this thread gets invoked.

Please let me know if any further inputs are required for you to respond. Thanks.
Do check the Ans. collected from the responses' given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Condition variables are the best bet  Possibly semaphores depending on what you are really doing.

(2) Yes, unless there is something fundamentally racy about your `send` function i.e. you are depending on some particular order of sends between the threads.  Otherwise you need to protect shared resources with mutexes.

(3) `pthread_join` will continue blocking until the thread you are waiting on completes.  Note that there is no guarantee that threads will complete in any order so if you are waiting on th[0] it is possible that 1 and 2 will complete first and you'll just pick them up in the loop when you get to them.

Comment: How can I use the gcount variable to wait inside the "same_func()
". Because right now, I make use of all the global variables available to sleep but this means all the threads quit from same_func() once the condition fails. But I want the thread to wait until the "global count" that is unique to the thread condition is met.

Comment: same_func is your thread's start function.  Create a struct containing whatever variables you need and pass a pointer to them to same_func as the 4th parameter to `pthread_create`. same_func passes it on to callback, much as you are currently doing.

Comment: Yeah Duck. I found this procedure helpful. I needed threads to maintain their own local copies and creating a structure with the count variable with all parameters required by my thread solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a conditional variable to wait for the `gcount` variables to reach zero:

```
int gcount[3];
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthraed_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void same_func(void *val)
{
   //Perform sending of this val using send() function for 10 times in each thread.
   // Basically I will be sending some specific data along with "val"

   /* Wait for all `gcount[]` values to reach zero */
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
   while (gcount[0] > 0 || gcount[1] > 0 || gcount[2] > 0)
       pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

In the callback function you need to signal the condition variable:

```
void callback(void *val)
{
  //Performs some work

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

   if(val == arg[0])
       gcount[0]--;

   if(val == arg[1])
       gcount[1]--;

   if(val == arg[2])
       gcount[2]--;

   if (gcount[0] <= 0 && gcount[1] <= 0 && gcount[2] <= 0)
       pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    
}
```

Comment: I think this is basically the code OP is looking for but he wants to bust out of the quagmire of waiting on all 3 at the same time.  IOW he wants each thread sending 10 msgs and then for each individual thread to block on its counter until all 10 replies have returned.  So basically this with one gcount element and an associated condvar per thread.

Comment: This will make all the threads to exit way before the entire thread functionality is performed when only one of the threads might have completed its work.

Comment: No, with this code no thread will exit until *all* the `gcount[]` variables reach zero.  This is based on the condition in the `while () sleep();` loop in your question.